# SSL error when certificate has been added to keychain

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, homebrew

I have followed some tutorials in adding a self-cert to my local environment, mainly this one [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate). I've added my certificate to the keychain and it is now marked as trusted for all users. But I'm still getting the error below. I've never tried to do this before and unsure now of the problem and how to fix it. Any advice would be great

[image]

**Update**
Steffen's answer helped me fixed this so I have awarded the points to him. I used this link for reference https://serversforhackers.com/video/self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in theory a certificate for `*.dev` will match `test.dev` in practice most browsers do not allow wildcards on the second level, i.e. `*.com` or `*.org`. It does not help that `dev` is currently not a public top level domain.

I recommend that you instead issue yourself the certificate without the wildcard (`test.dev`) or use an additional level for your hostnames.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, I will try this and report back